# Set proxy settings and proxy authentication

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, powershell, internet-explorer

I've asked this question on StackOverflow but it's not getting lots of attention, I thought it would be better to port it here:

I'm new to `PowerShell`, and I'm tired of changing `proxy settings` and `proxy authentication` every time I go to the university, is there a way to do that using PowerShell Commands , like using PowerShell script to enter the proxy address and the port and the authentication, instead of using the graphical windows `InternetOptions>Connections>LanSettings` (I assume that exists), if yes how can I do it?

I've searched the web and StackOverflow but I had different answers that didn't target what I want.

Comment: This has nothing to do with professional systems adminstration in a business setting. I'm voting to move to SuperUser, where it will be appropriate. FYI, did you know Google has a lot of good answers for this?

Comment: @mfinni : Thx for the mention of SuperUser, I'll delete the question my self, For Google, I do know it has lots of answers for this, I mentioned this in the question

Comment: Don't delete it, I've already provided an answer. Let it get voted-to-move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These settings are in the registry. Here's what they look like. You can change the ones you need to with `Set-ItemProperty`.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>cd HKCU:\"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
[PS] HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings>Get-ItemProperty .


PSPath                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settin
                            gs
PSParentPath              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
PSChildName               : Internet Settings
PSDrive                   : HKCU
PSProvider                : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
IE5_UA_Backup_Flag        : 5.0
User Agent                : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Win32)
EmailName                 : User@
PrivDiscUiShown           : 1
EnableHttp1_1             : 1
WarnOnIntranet            : 1
MimeExclusionListForCache : multipart/mixed multipart/x-mixed-replace multipart/x-byteranges
AutoConfigProxy           : wininet.dll
UseSchannelDirectly       : {1, 0, 0, 0}
PrivacyAdvanced           : 0
ProxyEnable               : 0
EnableNegotiate           : 1
MigrateProxy              : 1
WarnOnPost                : {1, 0, 0, 0}
UrlEncoding               : 0
SecureProtocols           : 2720
ZonesSecurityUpgrade      : {246, 23, 219, 248, 142, 45, 207, 1}
DisableCachingOfSSLPages  : 0
WarnonZoneCrossing        : 0
CertificateRevocation     : 1
ProxyHttp1.1              : 1
ProxyOverride             : <-loopback>
EnableAutodial            : 0
NoNetAutodial             : 0
AutoConfigURL             : http://not.disclosing.network.name:8080/hostedconfig/PAC/bunchastuff
```

Comment: You should give an example of the usage of Set-ItemProperty that you recommend using.